# Prove that if a production function is such that f'>0 and f''<0, then f'<Average Product

Tags: production-function, producer-theory, proof

I was told in class that if we have a production function such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$, then we have that the marginal product is less than the average product. That is $f'(x)<\frac{f(x)}{x}$. This is not a result that I am required to prove in class, I am just proving this out of curiosity. I will show you what I have so far:

Proof: Suppose $f''(x)<0$. Let us define average product as $AP$. That is,
$$AP:=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
$$\Longrightarrow AP'=\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^{2}}$$
Since $sign(x^{2})>0, \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, we know that $sign(AP')=sign(f'(x)x-f(x))$.
Now I am stuck. I can see that if $AP'<0$, then our result easily follows. That is, if average product is decreasing, then $f'(x)<AP$. That being said, I am not able to see the connection between the assumptions I made for the proof (f'>0 and f''<0) and slope(AP)<0. Would anyone be able to give me some insight into what I am missing. I can take the second derivative of average product and see that

$$AP''=\frac{(f''(x)x+f'(x)-f'(x))x^{2}-2x(f'(x)x-f(x))}{x^{4}}=\frac{f''(x)x^{3}-2x^{2}f'(x)-2xf(x)}{x^{4}}$$

and sign(AP'')=sign(numerator) once again. Since $f''<0$, and $f',f>0$, then clearly the slope of the slope of AP is decreasing. That is, average product is (increasing or decreasing) at a decreasing rate. But this doesn't give me any further insight into the sign of AP.

Comment: Your calim is not true without further restriction on $f$. If $f(0)=0$ you should be able to prove it using the inequality of concavity.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $f''<0$ implies strict concavity and hence

$$tf(y) + (1-t)f(x)<f(ty+(1-t)x) \Leftrightarrow f(y) - f(x)<\frac{f(ty+(1-t)x)-f(x)}{t}$$

$$f(y) - f(x)<\frac{f(x + t(y-x))-f(x)}{t(y-x)} (y-x),$$

now let $t$ go to 0 to get

$$f(y) - f(x)<f'(x) (y-x),$$

Finally, to get the result you are interested in letting $y=0$ and using that $f(0)=0$ it follows that

$$f'(x) < \frac{f(x)}{x}.$$